# selenium driver.page_source equivalent in requests lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to move my webscraper from selenium to requests only (speed). I have trouble with getting proper html source of webpage in requests.

1 - old selenium code:

```
driver.get(spolka)
page = driver.page_source
print(page)
doc = lh.fromstring(page)
```

2 - new requests code:

```
page = requests.get(spolka)
page = page.content
print(page)
doc = lh.fromstring(page)
```

1. selenium code - works as expected - loaded page is usable with xpath(). when printed page is nicely formatted in multi lines. it misses out the `<xml>` tag header
2. requests code - somehow works but is not usable with xpath. when printed page have strange letter 'b' at the start before `<xml tag>` at the very start. It is being printed as single long line.

I tried `page = page.text` but i am getting

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

Comment: I hate to suggest other packages in replies, but plain-jane `requests` doesn't have any means to work with CSS selectors. However, the requests author also has a `requests-html` package that has a `find` method that takes selectors.

Comment: Is it possible to give us the url? It's much easier to help that way. Try something like: `page = page.text.encode('utf-8')` or `page = page.content.decode()`

Comment: i think the header is causing trouble for the lxml lib: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>` view-source:https://mojeinwestycje.interia.pl/gie/prof/spolki/notowania?wlid=718&ks=1

Comment: After removing firsrt 45 characters the error is no more, however old working xpath expressions (from selenium) seems not to be working anymore

Comment: looks like this previously working expression(on driver.page_source from selenium) is not finding anything anymore (on page.text from requests)  `//table[5]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td'`, some simplier xpath expressions still work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decode it, try something like:

```
page = bytes(page.txt)
```

or

```
tmp = str(page.txt)
page = tmp.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
```

Comment: tried both, no change in output :-(. My guess is something with encoding/binary mode but for the moment I am stuck